# Reledmac and reledpar - Can a column text extend to following column in the page if there is space?

Tags: reledmac, reledpar, wrapfig

I would like to have a layout with 2 columns for parallel texts. But at times the text in one column is much more than in the other. Let say column 1 is only 10 lines, and the parallel column 2 is 50 lines. The regular behaviour leaves a lot of white space in column 1 and continue column 2 in a following page. But can, at line 11, the text of column 2 "expand" to column 1 automatically? I know how to do this manually by closing the 2 columns environment and switch to normal 1 column for the remaining text of column 2. Just wondering if there is a way to automize the process so the text reformats when I change it...
I also have to point out that I'm a LaTex beginner, sorry if my question is not sharp enough...

Comment: Normally text1 would be in column1 to be distinguished from text2 in column2. If you put both texts in one column then how is the reader to distinguish which is which?

Comment: The comment of Simon (below) shows what I had in mind graphically. I try to better explain what I have ideally in mind: Text 1 in column 1 and text 2 in column 2 are related at certain defined nodes, and text 2 wraps around text 1 (and viceversa) when it is longer. When text 2 wraps around text 1 the doc becomes only mono column (column 2) and at the next nodes it becomes two columns again. To better understand: Text 2 is a commentary of text 1, not a translation, so the length is variable. Hope I made my thinking clearer and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the linguist tools of `reledmac` and `reledpar`, one way is to wrap the shorter text  with  the longest.  The package `wrapfig` deals with figures  (and tables) so the text should be made a pseudo figure (with `tikz`). Of course it will not split across two pages.

[image: a]

`\setlength\intextsep{0pt}`  will suppress the blank line after the short text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% kant like dummy tex

%\setlength\intextsep{0pt} % optional

\begin{document}        
    
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth} % l= left
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={text width=0.48\textwidth,minimum width=0.48\textwidth,align= justify,inner sep=0pt}]
        \node {\kant[1]};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
2.  \lipsum[2]
3.  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `tikz` to make a figure, it is possible to define a new float to satisfy `wrapfig`,  using the `newfloat` package.

In this case `ShortText` was defined, so the `wrapShortText` environment will do the wrapping. The result is the same as the previous one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% kant like dummy tex

\usepackage{wrapfig} % added <<<<<<
\usepackage{newfloat} % added <<<<<
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[placement={!ht}]{ShortText} % new float <<<<

%\setlength\intextsep{0pt} % optional

\begin{document}
    
\begin{wrapShortText}{l}{0.48\textwidth}
    \kant[1]
\end{wrapShortText}
% longer text
2.  \lipsum[2]
3.  \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the right layout I have in mind. I had also experimented with the wrapfig package, by using minipage for my text. I do need reledmac for its sophisticated footnotes system, and wrapfig and minipage are compatible (to my knowledge). Do you see any advantage using tikz rather than minipage for the text frame? Sorry I never used tikz... Also: The problem remains that every page would have to set up manually if I understand well... Do you see any way out ??? Thanks again!

Comment: @Haim Every case of short text should be done manually, in general in the final version, with many other adjustments. You do not need to learn tikz right now, put your text inside. Later, if you found it useful, it can be defined a macro or an environment for less typing. The `wrapfig` only works for figures or tables, not miniframes, and a using miniframe alone will no wrap the longer text. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Very clear Simon. I get it... Please see also my answer to Peter above. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @Haim Please see the update I made to the answer to simplify the code and avoid `tikz`.  The only limitation that remains with this (floats) approach is that floats, like a figure, do not cross page boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I tried and it works with the above limitations. But another limitation I see is that I cannot put foot notes to the short text in the float. Also, footnotes in the long text that wrap around have strange behaviour (switching from 2 to 1 column as the text switches)

Comment: @Haim If you want to follow this approach, you'd better post another question showing the new issues.

Comment: Thanks Simon, understood!